# Target all images that are not the first attachment

Tags: php, attachments

I'm querying image attachments on a template I'm writing.
For a layout purpose, I'd like to apply a css class to all the images that are not the first.

Here is the code I'm currently working on, I'm stuck with the last if statement. But my php knowledge is very shallow, hope someone can help me writing this.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                        echo the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , 'full' );
                        echo $img_count > 1 ? 'rel="'.$post->ID.'"' : '';
                        // OK all my post attached images are visible. 
                }
        }
                    //if image is not the first one then add class="fantome"
                    if ( $attachments != $first_attachment ) {
                        echo '<a class="fantome">';

                    }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just modifying  your code please check. Hope it will help.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'order' => 'ASC' );
     $i = 0;
$attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {

            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                  if($i != 0){
                   $class = 'fantome';
                 }else{ $class = '';}  
              $imgarr = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID,'full');
             /*---------------this will output your image and class------- */
              echo '<img class="'.$class.'" src="'.$imgarr[0].'" />';
             $i++;
            }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Hey it's working but I just lost the link tags around the images... Will look after that. Could you please tell me what `$i = 0;` and `$i++;` are doing?

Comment: at first fetching the attachemnts in a ascending order.after that this for counting the first attachment or not

Comment: if you want to add link around the images just put this
echo '<a href="your-link"><img class="'.$class.'" src="'.$imgarr[0].'" /></a>';